# Need help in solving type mismatch error (value is not a member of Double) in Scala

Tags: scala

I am using Amazon Deequ Scala library for data quality check. The format for calling methods in Deequ library below

```
  checks = hasDistinctness(Seq("column1","column2"), _ >= 0.70)
```

I was planning to pass the condition check(>= 0.70) from config file.

code:

```
 val chk_val  = config.getString("chk_val")  
 println(chk_val)    // ">= 0.70"
 checks = hasDistinctness(Seq("column1","column2"),_ chk_val)
```

Method definition in Deequ library:

```
def hasDistinctness(
  columns: Seq[String], assertion: Double => Boolean,
  hint: Option[String] = None)
: CheckWithLastConstraintFilterable = {

addFilterableConstraint { filter => distinctnessConstraint(columns, assertion, filter, hint) }
 }
```

Error:

> Error: value chk_val is not a member of Double

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_ >= 0.70` is a function that compares it's element with 0.70. desugaring the `_` it would look like `value => value >= o.70`

Compiler understands `_ chk_val` as a postfix-notation call to `chk_val` on whatever is passed to the function. Desugared, it would look like `value => value.chk_val`

Obviously, there is no `chk_val` member on the Double - and that's exactly what compiler tells you.

So, `_` is not a black magic - it doesn't just magically parse the string and turn it into executable code :) In order to get the condition from the config file, you'd need to parse it into a function - probably the most straightforward (and risky, and probably compiler will not type check it) is to use some sort of `eval` functionality (e.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31117964/882918), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612322/dynamically-parse-a-string-and-return-a-function-in-scala-using-reflection-and-i)).

The faster, easier and more straightforward (but probably less flexible and less scalable) approach is to probably define a parser yourself. Something along the lines of:

```
def parseCondition(input: String): Double => Boolean = {
  val splitInput = input.split(" ")
  // You might want to add some validation - e.g. ">=0.7" will just throw here
  val (operator, operand) = (splitInput.first, splitInput.last)
  operator match {
     case ">=": _ >= operand
     case ">": _ > operand
     case "<": _ < operand
     ...
  }
}
```

Or maybe use Atto::

- [Atto homepage](https://tpolecat.github.io/atto/)
- [article on how to use it](https://medium.com/synerise/yet-another-arithmetic-parser-in-scala-43dad055d81f)